# Clearcase viewname.tmp folder deletion

Tags: clearcase

My ClearCase storage location has something like `viewname.tmp` folders, I believe they got created for my views.

I would like to know how can I delete those `.tmp` folders from my storage location (eg : `\\server1\views\username`).
If I do with delete button then  "`Access denied`" message is coming.

Comment: Do you have also the regular '`.vws`' folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view storage ending with `.tmp` (`/path/to/myview.vws.tmp`) is only created during a `rmview`, in order to make the view storage directory immediately unavailable.

It can linger on if there some sort of conflict due to:

- an anti-virus software (see [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21188215))
- a cross-platform access (windows => linux through samba, as described in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=246955))

If the `lsview myview` states the view doesn't exist anymore, you can safely get rid of that view storage once you figured you what is blocking it from being deleted.
Or you can also simply leave it here: it won't harm the creation of new ClearCase views.

Comment: lsview is showing my view and its storage location. But now how can i delte the view . rmview command is not working. showing error ... cleartool: Error: Unable to open file cleartool: Error: \\srvccm01\xxx\xxxx\x\xxx cleartool: Error: Unable to remove vie                                                                   More over new view with the same name is not being created

Comment: the sample tmp folder name is hdsn_projectname_view.tmp not hdsn_projectname_view.vws.tmp

Comment: @srinannapa: if `rmview` is failing, you still can "unregister" the view (this is an operation which will only affect the central registry server and won't touch any file or view storsage file on your workstation): `cleartool unregister -view -uuid ...` and `ct rmtag -view view-tag`.